# What's the goal of using CMS or Framework instead of PHP programming

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system

Firstable i hate CMS, i tryed drupal and joomla once upon a time but i couldn't understand a thing! Everyone i talk with seem to claim that today you cannot develop a website without a CMS..

I will soon have a contract for 3 websites. The major features will be :

- eCommerce shop (cart, credit card paiement).
- Backend administration for the shop. (Create new articles, billing management, stock management).
- Backend creation of stories.
- Community comments with aproval from admin
- Community directories registration with management from admin

I am good PHP Developer with strong knowledges of formular validation, sessions, db queries, javascript/jquery, ajax, url rewriting, caching systems.

I'm pretty confortable developping website from scratch since i always did like that in the past. I like to have easy control on the design and customize each page like i want.

What's the goal of using either a CMS or a framework for this project since i have maybe only 1 month to learn using them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The goal of using a framework is that you can reuse code that others have written and validated and can spend your time and skills on the more specific bits. 
Using a framework therefore will save you time, even though it will take some time to figure out how the authors have laid stuff out.

I don't think a cms will help you write a web shop. But there are open source web shops too that you can adapt. For example http://www.opencart.com/ or http://www.prestashop.com/

If you have only a month, magento may be a bit much.

Comment: +1 , Or even magento or prestashop

Comment: @AlirezaFallah I've added a link to prestashop. Would you agree that Magento is a bit much?

Comment: Thanks for that explaination. I will look at theses shops. Also, why would i use cakephp/CodeIgniter/symphony instead of symply using common php features ?

Comment: To save time, not reinvent the wheel, adhere to best practices, use tested and secure code. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/what-is-cakephp-why-use-it.html

Answer (score 0):

> Firstable

...First of all?

I have trouble with these two statements:

> I am good PHP Developer with strong knowledges of formular validation,
>   sessions, db queries, javascript/jquery, ajax, url rewriting, caching
>   systems.

and

> i tryed drupal and joomla once upon a time but i couldn't understand a
>   thing!

How are both of these things possible? It's not some mysterious black box, it's not closed source, you can read all the code that it's made of and as you said you have strong knowledge of all the things it's comprised of.

> Create new articles
>
> Backend creation of stories
>
> Community comments with aproval from admin
>
> Community directories registration with management from admin

All of these are pretty standard CMS activities. If you feel like re-inventing the wheel, go ahead, but don't be surprised when the client keeps saying "why can't it do X like this other site" (That uses drupal) until you end up putting in lots of hours to finally simulate code you could have re-used.

Comment: Yeah sure, i will read the code of the hundred files so i will understand how it works.. Sorry but it must be me because when i think of a CMS, i should easily manage my content. But after the installation i just don't understand how to manage my content (in joomla ie), that's why i hate them